# Change arrow colour

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, menu

I am trying to make a GUI program using tkinter and python3. When I try to create a submenu for a menu in the menubar, I get a 3D arrow unlike the arrow I usually get in other programs.

```
from tkinter import *


MainWindow = Tk()
MainWindow.title('MenuBar')
MainWindow.geometry(str(MainWindow.winfo_screenwidth()) + 'x' + str(MainWindow.winfo_screenheight()))




#Menu_Bar object
menubar = Menu(MainWindow, bd=0, activeborderwidth=0)

#File Menu Object
file_menu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0, bd=0, activeborderwidth=0)
file_menu.add_command(label ='  New', command = None)
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label ='  Open', command = None)
#Create a sub-menu for Open-Recent
Open_Recent = Menu(file_menu, tearoff=0, bd=0,activeborderwidth=0)
Open_Recent.add_command(label = 'file1', command=None)
Open_Recent.add_command(label = 'file2', command=None)
Open_Recent.add_command(label = 'file3', command=None)

file_menu.add_cascade(label ='  Open Recent', command = None, menu=Open_Recent)

file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label ='  Save', command = None)
file_menu.add_command(label ='  Save as', command = None)
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label ='  Import FIle as Module', command = None)
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label ='  Exit', command = MainWindow.destroy)
menubar.add_cascade(label ='Menu', menu = file_menu)



#Edit Menu Object
edit_menu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0, bd=0, activeborderwidth=0)
edit_menu.add_command(label ='  Undo', command = None)
edit_menu.add_command(label ='  Redo', command = None)
edit_menu.add_separator()
edit_menu.add_command(label ='  UI', command = None)
edit_menu.add_command(label ='  System', command = None)
edit_menu.add_separator()
edit_menu.add_command(label ='  Rename', command = None)
edit_menu.add_command(label ='  Batch Rename', command = None)
menubar.add_cascade(label ='Edit', menu = edit_menu)


#Assets Menu Object
Asset_menu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0, bd=0, activeborderwidth=0)
Asset_menu.add_command(label ='  Set Folder', command = None)
Asset_menu.add_command(label ='  Export as Asset', command = None)
Asset_menu.add_command(label ='  Import Asset', command = None)
Asset_menu.add_command(label ='  Browse Assets', command = None)
Asset_menu.add_command(label ='  Set Icon', command = None)
Asset_menu.add_command(label ='  Remove Icon', command = None)
menubar.add_cascade(label ='  Assets', menu = Asset_menu)


#Adding Menubar to the window
MainWindow.config(menu=menubar)

mainloop()
```

Here is a screenshow from VSCode(the look I am going for)
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcvli.png)

And here is what I am getting
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReUYN.png)

Comment: Tk draws its own widgets, so it doesn't look/behave like the native ones. This hour it's the arrow bothering you, the next hour it'd be something else. If you want native look, use wxwidgets or somesuch.

Comment: @NiccoloM.: in the case of menus, on most platforms tkinter does _not_ draw its own widgets. It relies on native widgets for menus.

Answer (score 0):

I just added `bg = "black", fg = "white",activebackground="white"` to each menu. I'm not sure if it's the right answer, but the result looks the exactly like image 1.

**EDIT:**

full code with the small changes.

```
from tkinter import *


MainWindow = Tk()
MainWindow.title('MenuBar')
MainWindow.geometry(str(MainWindow.winfo_screenwidth()) + 'x' + str(MainWindow.winfo_screenheight()))

#Menu_Bar object
menubar = Menu(MainWindow, bd=0, activeborderwidth=0, bg = "black", fg = "white",activebackground="white")

#File Menu Object
file_menu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0, bd=0, activeborderwidth=0, bg = "black", fg = "white",activebackground="white")
file_menu.add_command(label ='  New', command = None)
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label ='  Open', command = None)
#Create a sub-menu for Open-Recent
Open_Recent = Menu(file_menu, tearoff=0, bd=0,activeborderwidth=0, bg = "black", fg = "white",activebackground="white")
Open_Recent.add_command(label = 'file1', command=None)
Open_Recent.add_command(label = 'file2', command=None)
Open_Recent.add_command(label = 'file3', command=None)

file_menu.add_cascade(label ='  Open Recent', command = None, menu=Open_Recent)

file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label ='  Save', command = None)
file_menu.add_command(label ='  Save as', command = None)
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label ='  Import FIle as Module', command = None)
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label ='  Exit', command = MainWindow.destroy)
menubar.add_cascade(label ='Menu', menu = file_menu)



#Edit Menu Object
edit_menu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0, bd=0, activeborderwidth=0,bg = "black", fg = "white",activebackground="white")
edit_menu.add_command(label ='  Undo', command = None)
edit_menu.add_command(label ='  Redo', command = None)
edit_menu.add_separator()
edit_menu.add_command(label ='  UI', command = None)
edit_menu.add_command(label ='  System', command = None)
edit_menu.add_separator()
edit_menu.add_command(label ='  Rename', command = None)
edit_menu.add_command(label ='  Batch Rename', command = None)
menubar.add_cascade(label ='Edit', menu = edit_menu)


#Assets Menu Object
Asset_menu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0, bd=0, activeborderwidth=0,bg = "black", fg = "white",activebackground="white")
Asset_menu.add_command(label ='  Set Folder', command = None)
Asset_menu.add_command(label ='  Export as Asset', command = None)
Asset_menu.add_command(label ='  Import Asset', command = None)
Asset_menu.add_command(label ='  Browse Assets', command = None)
Asset_menu.add_command(label ='  Set Icon', command = None)
Asset_menu.add_command(label ='  Remove Icon', command = None)
menubar.add_cascade(label ='  Assets', menu = Asset_menu)


#Adding Menubar to the window
MainWindow.config(menu=menubar)

mainloop()
```

Comment: It did not work. It might have something to do with my Operating System which is Ubuntu.

Comment: It should work because I also work with Ubuntu.  I have uploaded the full code with the minimal changes.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/WekWZOU

Here is the result I am getting after running your code.

Comment: I tried this on my current system (Windows 10). Active items are white on white, and I don't see the arrow. Needless to say, the color scheme you picked is different than my normal applications. I'll repeat my recommendation: either accept what Tk gives you, or switch to some other toolkit.